# <li> tags with forms in are closing when clicking the inner input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vLfqsp5s/

Okay so I have an issue I can't quite resolve, I have a `< ul >` element with many `< li >` sub elements in, they all are correct, the issue I am having is with JQuery. When I click the `< li >` element it shows as intended but if I click any of the elements inside it, it'll close back up. I have a form in there I wish for users to be able to type in, but if I click to go and enter text the `< li >` element closes up. How can I prevent this?

```
            $( "li" ).click(function() {
                $( "li" ).not(this).each(function() {
                    $(this).children(".content").slideUp();
                    $(this).children(".comment").slideUp();
                    $(this).children(".sendComment").slideUp();
                });
                $(this).children(".content").slideToggle();
                $(this).children(".comment").slideToggle();
                $(this).children(".sendComment").slideToggle();
            });
```

Thank you.

Comment: providing as a fiddle would be a great idea :)

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/vLfqsp5s/2/

Comment: Yes! Well that was simple... Thank you, im new to jquery, i know the animating basics. Again thank you that solves my issue. :)

Comment: Please never put `[SOLVED]` or similar into your title.  The question is already marked as having an accepted answer.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on any element within the other, the event will bubble up. You just need to check the `event.target` before taking any action.
You can also simplify your code a lot (look at the chaining and that you actually don't need to use `.each`):

```
$( "li" ).on("click", function (e) {
    // If what has been clicked isn't the li (could be its children)
    // we just ignore the event.
    if (e.target != this)
        return;

    // You can chain methods and also include many classes in the selector.
    $( "li" ).not(this).children(".content, .comment, .sendComment").slideUp();

    $(this).children(".content, .comment, .sendComment").slideToggle();
});
```

[event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vLfqsp5s/6/)

Answer (score 0):

hi i have updated your jsfiddle..

code:-

```
$( "li" ).click(function(e) {

if(!$(e.target).is("li"))
    return false;
    $(this).children(".content").slideToggle();
    $(this).children(".comment").slideToggle();
    $(this).children(".sendComment").slideToggle();
});
```

see the working example:-http://jsfiddle.net/vLfqsp5s/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this also

```
    $( "li" ).click(function() {
    if($('.sendComment').hasClass('slide')){
        return false;        
    }else{ 
    $( "li" ).not(this).each(function() {
        $(this).children(".content").slideUp();
        $(this).children(".comment").slideUp();
        $(this).children(".sendComment").slideUp();             
    });
    $(this).children(".sendComment").addClass('slide');
    $(this).children(".content").slideToggle();
    $(this).children(".comment").slideToggle();
    $(this).children(".sendComment").slideToggle();
    }    
    });
```